# Limit of a composite function.

Tags: limits

Here:
$$\lim_{x\to n} {f(g(x))}$$
When the exact amount of $g(x)$ in $x=n$ is k and it's Constant in that area, what do we do next?
Should I approach the $f(x)$ in k or just calculate $f(k)$?
And why?
I know it's superficial but it confused me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have to take the limit for $f$ also.

Comment: if $f, g$ are continuous at $a,$ then $\lim_\limits {x\to a} (f\circ g)(x) = (f\circ g)(a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the case you intend to describe is as follows:

- $g(n) = k$ in a neighbourhood of $n$. This means there is an interval $(a,b)$ (which might be possibly quite small) with $n \in (a,b)$ and $g(x) = k$ for all $x \in (a,b)$
- Besides this you need $f$ to be defined at $k$. (Below, you will see why.)

In this case you are totally right in just calculating $f(k)$ as the searched for limit. Here is why:

Let $x_i\stackrel{i\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}n$. Then, it follows that $g(x_i) = k$ for all $i\geq I$ from a certain index $I$ on. This is so because $g$ is constant on the interval $(a,b)$ which contains $n$.

So, the sequence $f(g(x_i))$ is only well defined if $f(k)$ is defined. But then $f(g(x_i)) = f(k)$ for all $i\geq I$, which means $\displaystyle\lim_{i\to \infty}f(g(x_i))=f(k)$.

Since this holds for any sequence $x_i\stackrel{i\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}n$ in the domain of $g$, you have $\displaystyle\boxed{\lim_{x\to n}f(g(x))=f(k)}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems like f(x) must be continues in x=k, am I right? Otherwise we say the limit does not exist?

Comment: @BoshraAlef In this special case the continuity of $f$ is not necessary. It only needs to be defined at $k$.

Comment: Let the g(x) be |x|+|x-2| and f(x) be [x], and the variable approaches to 1.5. So here we say that $\lim_{x\to 1.5} {f(g(x))}$ is two?

Comment: @BoshraAlef :  You are completely right. The limit is well defined. $g(x)=2$ in a neighbourhood of $1.5$ and, hence, $f(g(x))=2$ in the same neighbourhood of $1.5$. Hence, $\lim_{x\to 1.5}f(g(x))=2$.

Comment: You may also graph it:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7By%3D%7Cx%7C%2B%7Cx-2%7C%2Cy%3DFloor%28%7Cx%7C%2B%7Cx-2%7C%29%2Cx%3D1.5%7D%2C+x%3D0..4

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now I got it:)

Comment: You are welcome :-)